# CloudFormation - Splitting string by first appearance of delimiter

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a CloudFormation template that receives a bucket ARN that can include folders and I need to split the string by bucket name and bucket key.

For example, the input is going to be: `arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/test/demo`
And I need a way to retrieve the bucket arn which is `arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket` and `test/demo` separately.

I tried to use `Fn::Join`, `Fn::Select` and `Fn::Split` functions to receive the expected results but I faced a problem to join all splited parts.

```
"Fn::Join": [
    "-",
    {
      "Fn::Select": [
        1,
        {
          "Fn::Split": [
            "/",
            "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/test/demo"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

I know that I can create a lambda that will make this separation but I'm trying to prevent it.

Thanks